# How do I call all the variable in the while loop outside the loop to open my modal dynamically?

Tags: php, modal-dialog, simplemodal

**PHP**
as you can see in the below code while loop starts and end as some point

```
     <?php 
          $queryt = "SELECT * FROM events";
          $resultt = mysqli_query($con, $queryt);
          $countt = mysqli_num_rows($resultt);
          while ($rt = $resultt->fetch_assoc()){ //This is where while loop starts
              $id=$rt['id'];             
              $title = $rt['title'];
              //Here the variable title and id change every time the while loop runs
              $content = $rt['content'];
              $test=$title;
     ?>
    <div class="about-us section-padding <?php echo $id;?>" id="session"  data-scroll-index='1'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 section-title text-center">
                    <h3><?php echo $title;?></h3>
                    <span class="section-title-line"></span> 
                </div>
                          
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-50">
            <div class="section-info">
                <div class="sub-title-paragraph">
                    <h4>You can conquer the world.</h4>
                     <h5>If you have right set of mind and thus you can rule the world.</h5>
                      <?php  echo $content;
                      ?>                
<a href="#" ><i style="color: black;width:100px;" id="<?php echo $title;?>" onclick="getId(this)" class="fas fa-edit"></i> </a>
                 </div>
                                  
<a  class="anchor-btn" >Swipe for more<i class="fas fa-arrow-right pd-lt-10"> </i></a>
                </div>
                          
              </div>
                        
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
                    
<?php } ?> //Here the while loop ends
//Suppose the id=1 for 1st time the while loop runs, I want the same id 1 to be displayed below in place of $id in modals's but what is happening is as mentioned the while loop is closed above hence the last value stored in $id is fetched here, instead I want whenever what ever the id is should be fetched here and the rest of the code should be executed.
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="myModalcontent" class="modal">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <span class="closedd closed" id = "spancontent_">&times;</span>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="indexckpostevents.php" method="post">
               <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor">
                <?php
                    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM events where id=$id ");
```

**Suppose the id=1 for 1st time the while loop runs, I want the same id 1 to be displayed here above in place of $id but what is happening is as mentioned the while loop is closed above hence the last value stored in $id is fetched here, instead I want whenever what ever the id is should be fetched here and the rest of the code should be executed.**

```
                            if ($query) {
                             while ($rowcon = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                              echo $rowcon['content']; 
                             }
                            }
                        ?>
                        </textarea>
                </div>
       
                        <script>
                         var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
                         CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor );
                        </script>
                        <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $title?>">                   
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submittitle" >Preview</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" id = "cancelcontent_">Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       //Edit Content Event Modal end
```

Comment: How to pass data from the parent document to a re-usable modal? Data attributes.  This is a duplicate question.

Comment: `id="session"` in a loop makes your html document invalid because you are writing duplicate ids.